# Copy Data from one field to another on fill via remote action

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I have a field which is an autocomplete and data is fetched to it by remote action. I want when that field will get populate, the below text field should filled up with same data and if we add same values, it should throw exception.

```
public with sharing class AutoCompleteController {

    // Instance fields
    public String searchTerm {get; set;}
    public String selectedMovie {get; set;}

    // Constructor
    public AutoCompleteController() {

    }

    // JS Remoting action called when searching for a movie name
    @RemoteAction
    public static List<Geography__c> searchMovie(String searchTerm) {
        System.debug('Movie Name is: '+searchTerm );
        List<Geography__c> movies = Database.query('Select Id, Name from Geography__c where name like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '%\'');
        return movies;
    }

}
```

VF Page -

```
    <apex:page controller="AutoCompleteController" >
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" />
        <apex:styleSheet value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <style>
            .displayNone { 
                display:none; 
            }
            .displayBlock {
                display:block;
            }
            .ui-autocomplete-loading { 
                background: white url(/img/loading32.gif) right center no-repeat;
                background-size:15px 15px; 
            }
            .placeHolder {
                font-style: italic;
            }
        </style>

        <apex:form id="autoCompleteForm" >

            <apex:pageBlock id="searchBlock" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="searchSection" title="Find me a movie to rent" columns="1" >
                     <apex:outputLabel value="Movie Name" for="movieBox" />
                     <apex:outputPanel >
                         <apex:inputText id="movieTextBox" value="{!searchTerm}" styleClass="placeHolder"/>
                         <apex:inputHidden id="searchMovieId" value="{!selectedMovie}" />
<input type="text" size="40" id="continentsText"/>// the value should get populate here and should get adding with semi colon delimiter
                     </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var PLACEHOLDER = 'Enter Movie Name Here'; 
            var movieObjects;
            var queryTerm;

            $('[id$=movieTextBox]').autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function(request, response) {
                            queryTerm = request.term;
                            AutoCompleteController.searchMovie(request.term, function(result, event){
                                if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                      alert(event.message);
                                } else {
                                     movieObjects = result;
                                     response(movieObjects);
                                }
                            });
                       },
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                        $('[id$=movieTextBox]').val( ui.item.Name );
                        return false;
                        },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $('[id$=movieTextBox]').val( ui.item.Name );
                            $('[id$=searchMovieId]').val( ui.item.Id );
                            return false;
                        },
             })
             .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                var entry = "<a>" + item.Name;

                entry = entry + "</a>";
                entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( entry )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            // Add or remove placeholder values
            $('[id$=movieTextBox]').val(PLACEHOLDER);
            $('[id$=movieTextBox]').on("focus",  function(event){
                $tgt = $(event.target);
                if($tgt.val() === PLACEHOLDER ){
                    $tgt.val('');
                    $tgt.removeClass('placeHolder');
                }
            });
            $('[id$=movieTextBox]').on( "blur",  function(event){
                $tgt = $(event.target);
                if($tgt.val() === '' ){
                    $tgt.val(PLACEHOLDER);
                    $tgt.addClass('placeHolder');
                }
            });
        </script>

    </apex:page>
```

Comment: So, what's going wrong or what are you unsure about ? Please use the correct tags to attrackt the right people to your questions.